# jQuery two sequencial animations not working

Tags: jquery, animation

Got this pre-animation, and an alert popping up after 2 seconds. This works:

```
$('.tableContent').find('.turnEditPanel').animate({'height': 36}, 300).delay(1000).queue(function() {                   
   alert("HI");
 });
```

Now when I change the alert by other animation, affecting right the same div in order to revert the animation, it seems like it does not identify it or s.thing, as nothing happens..:

```
$('.tableContent').find('.turnEditPanel').animate({'height': 36}, 300).delay(1000).queue(function() {                   
   $('.tableContent').find('.turnEditPanel').animate({'height': 0}, 300);
 });
```

This neither works with (this):

```
$('.tableContent').find('.turnEditPanel').animate({'height': 36}, 300).delay(1000).queue(function() {                   
       $(this).animate({'height': 0}, 300);
     });
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?! Anyway, you don't need to use queue here, animate() method already use the queue

Comment: Thank you for your attention, already solved. No queue needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `.queue`, but you should probably just chain the event, or use the `complete` callback on the first call to `.animate()` instead.

Example using chaining:

```
$('.tableContent').find('.turnEditPanel').animate({'height': 36}, 300).delay(1000).animate({'height': 0}, 300);
```

Example using the complete callback:

```
$('.tableContent').find('.turnEditPanel').animate({'height': 36}, 300, function() {
  $(this).delay(1000).animate({'height': 0}, 300);
});
```

**Update**

As A. Wolff mentioned in his comment, `alert('HI')` works in `queue()` but `animate()` does not because calling animate inside queue callback will put it into the animation queue,  but it won't be run until you call the next item in the queue, for example:

```
.queue(function(next) {
    $(this).animate({'height': 0}, 300);
    next();
}); 

//next is shorthand for dequeue('fx'). "fx" is name of the default queue created by jQuery.
```

Comment: Thank you, I used .queue because on first try chaining method did not work, mostly sure due to a mistake. This works. In any case, do you know why alert runs but no animation, as seen on the question? I'll tick en 7 minutes.

Comment: @Biomehanika Because you need to explicetely dequeue it: `.queue(function(next) {                   
    $(this).animate({'height': 0}, 300);
    next();
 });`  next is shorthand for `dequeue('fx')`  That's because using animate inside queue callback will put it in queue and won't be call until you call next item in queue

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for the description, I was trying to figure it out myself as I've never manipulated the animation queue before.

Comment: @A.Wolff that cleared it up in my mind. thanks for the explanation

Comment: Thnk you very much. And in this case, that there is a piece of HTML changing, must I use queue? Because HTML changes before it inished first chained animation, even when it is placed after...:
                        $('.tableContent').find('.turnEditPanel').animate({'height': 36}, 300).delay(1000).animate({'height': 0}, 300).delay(100).html("HOLA").animate({'height': 220}, 500);

Comment: This example does NOT respect order, so must I solve this by queues?

Comment: @Biomehanika You need to use callbacks (like I showed in my example). Calling `.delay(1000)` only delays the next animation you put in the queue, it's not as if the code execution is _actually_ delayed for 1000ms. So when you call `.html()` at the end, the HTML changes **instantly**. You need to put that call to change the HTML inside a callback of one of your `.animate()` calls. That's what the callback is for, to execute code when the animation is finished. You do not need to use queues.

Comment: @Biomehanika Perhaps the following jsFiddle will better illustrate what I'm trying to say in my comment: http://jsfiddle.net/57hYC/. I've also included code that uses a callback, to show how it can be used.

Comment: i am about to check your info. very grateful Christian, Ill kep u informed.